# Where is the right place in my code to use the Strategy pattern

Tags: c++, strategy-pattern

I'm new with the design pattern approach. I am designing a game called Xonix. All the Movable Object handling has quite the same coding. I want to know when it is proper to use the stategy pattern in the below code:

Move is virtual.

```
void User::move(const dynamicO& mo, const staticO& so)
{
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    keyboard(x, y);
    m_sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

void User::keyboard(float& x, float& y)
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) { x = -18; y = 0; };
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) { x = 18; y = 0; };
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) { x = 0; y = -18; };
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) { x = 0; y = 18; };
}
```

The only thing that differs from one Object to another is the keyboard, in this case the keyboard is only for `User`, besides I omitted some extra code which is not so relevant for the question, it was more like a general question.

So my question is, should I use the strategy pattern only on `keyboard`, or should I use it on `move` to save lines of codes from all the objects and concentrate them in one file?

Comment: What about passing `x` and `y` as parameters to the `move()` function? This seems to be more natural and idiomatic for me. Any strategy to obtain `x` and `y` would be applied outside of that function then.

Comment: Personally, I would wrap the movement-related code into a base class like `Movable` which provides a `Movable::move()` method. Everything that is 'movable' would inherit from `Movable`. Here's an example of something similar with SFML: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php

Comment: It's also difficult to understand your code without some more context. What _overall problem_ are you trying to solve? Why do you think you need the strategy pattern? What other approaches have you considered? What does `keyboard` do and why the heck are `x` and `y` static? Feel free to [edit] your question anytime to help clarify

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, or how the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is applicable.

Comment: Reining in my snark-level a bit, don't go looking for ways to use patterns. Identify the problems you need to solve. If a pattern solves one or more of those problems, use it. If not, don't try to brute-force a pattern into the solution.

Comment: I see. I edited, but I don't think it matter anymore anyways. Was just looking to implement same line of code one time. Besides strategy pattern is used for different algorithms implementation, so I though it would be a case were I have different ways to implement my keyboard to different object, but i guess i was wrong.